# Create index column for n unique intervals in R

Tags: r, indexing, group-by, tidyverse, intervals

I have a column that looks like the following:

```
pscore  pscoreblocks
0.18    (.177, 0.187)
0.24    (0.237, 0.246)
0.07    (0.069, 0.079)
```

I created the pscoreblocks column by dividing the pscore column into 100 evenly spaced intervals.

```
dfc$pscoreblocks <- cut_interval(dfc$pscore, n=100)
```

How can I create a new column with a unique number for each of the 100 intervals?

```
pscore  pscoreblocks    block_number
0.18    (.177, 0.187)   3
0.24    (0.237, 0.246)  5
0.07    (0.069, 0.079)  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `pscoreblocks` to ineteger.

```
dfc$block_number <- as.integer(dfc$pscoreblocks)
```

You can also use `match` and `unique`

```
dfc$block_number <- match(dfc$pscoreblocks, unique(dfc$pscoreblocks))
```